# Jquery-ui datepicker with months and years menu rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a rails app where I want to choose a date of birth.  I'd like to use the jquery-ui datepicker for this but am not sure how to implement it into my rails app.

This is a screenshot of the options I want with the month and years menus to make selecting birthdates easier.

http://cl.ly/image/46152b372N1b

I'm really not sure where to start as far as setting this up in my application.js file as well as in my view.

Right now my view/form looks like this

```
   <%= f.text_field :patient_dob, :id => 'datepicker' %>
```

Here's my application.js

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
  });
});
```

Again, I'd like that to be a a jquery-ui datepicker with the month and years option to make selecting the birthdate easier.

If anyone can throw me some code to get started, I'd appreciate it. Right now when I click the text field, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you include *jquery.js*, *jquery-ui.js*, *jquery-ui.css* in your head html tag.
- jQuery and jQuery-ui javascript files should be declared only **once**. You can check this by right-clicking your webpage (eg. in chrome) and select *View Source Code*. Also, on Source Code click the jquery.js, jquery-ui.js, jquery-ui.css and application.js links and make sure that your code is in there (if you don't find the code expected, check your paths).
- application.js file should be declared **after** jquery and jquery-ui.

So your < head > should look like this:

```
<head>
  <meta [your code]>
  <title>[your code]</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application.js" %>
</head>
```

Comment: I've added this to my application.html.erb file.  And when I reload the form and click the text_field nothing happens.  I inspected the element and it shows: <input id="datepicker" name="patient[patient_dob]" size="30" type="text">

Answer (score 0):

After some searching and experimenting this code worked out for me.  It seems what I was using before either wasn't the object or I had it closed wrong.

```
$(function(){
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '1900:2013'      
  });
  $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');
});
```